# Vueify: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: gulp, ecmascript-6, browserify, vue.js, babeljs

I am using Vue.
This is how I'm building in my gulpfile:

```
browserify('./main.js')
.transform(vueify)
.bundle()
.pipe( fs.createWriteStream('./build/bundle.js') );
```

The problem is vueify doesn't handle the es6 exports in my .js files. It only works in .vue components.  It works with `module.exports`, but I'd like to take advantage of es6 code in my .js files.

When `bundle()` is called, I currently get the error:

`'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'`

Is there any way to modify the gulpfile to handle js files using es6 that my .vue components are importing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After hours of struggling, I finally figured it out.

1. Install babelify: `npm install --save-dev babelify`
2. Add this to the top of your gulpfile: `var babelify = require( 'babelify' )`;
3. Add `.transform( babelify )`:

   ```
   return browserify('./main.js') //tells browserify where to start, but doesn't run the resolve algorithm yet
   .transform( vueify ) //executes vueify to transform vue components to js
   .transform( babelify ) //executes babelify to transform es6 to es5
   .bundle() //runs the module resolve algorithm on all the require() statements      
   .pipe( fs.createWriteStream('./build/bundle.js') );
   ```

Comment: This was very usefull

Answer (score 2):

OK, I've been running into this for several days trying to get Axios to work with Vue and the OP's self-answer *saved me*.  That being said, I'm not using Gulp (yet) and had to do several different steps.

My problem was actually with the `import` command.  It would error during the Browserify *compile* and at runtime the error `axios is undefined` was ocurring.

The script section of my .vue file is as follows:

```
<script>
  import axios from 'axios';

  module.exports = {
    name: "address-search",
    data: function() {
      return {
        valid: false,
        hash: '',
        errors: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
      async validateAddress() {
        const query = `./validateAddress/` + this.hash;      
        try {
          const response = await axios.get(query);
          this.valid = response.data;
        } catch (e) {
          this.errors.push(e)
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

My *bundle command* is as follows:

```
browserify -t vueify -e public/javascripts/main.js -o public/javascripts/bundle.js
```

And during *compile* I was getting the error stated by the OP:

```
'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

The steps I took included:

1. Install babel-core: `npm install --save-dev babel-core`
2. Install babelify (per OP): `npm install --save-dev babelify`
3. Install bable-preset-es2015: `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015 babel-plugin-transform-runtime`
4. Rerun `browserify -t vueify -e public/javascripts/main.js -o public/javascripts/bundle.js`

**Voila!**  Now the `import` directive works and Axios is happy.

In retrospect, it is somewhat obvious why it didn't work in the first place (no mapping for the newer Javascript syntax) but I certainly hope this helps someone else get to delivering business value instead of spending too much time on library management.